# Using Jquery Ajax function for Ecommerce Category Layout? HOW?

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter, e-commerce

I am building a custom ecommerce site for a client of mine and I've decided that I want to use Ajax to repopulate the product layout when they choose an option. So for instance...

I have a list of colors. Red, blue, green, etc. When they click one of the colors I want to pass the ID of the color to the ajax function. It will go to a php function where it pulls a new list of products based on the color they chose. It returns a JSON object with all the products in it. THIS PART I CAN HANDLE.

So this is the part I need help on. I have never done this before so i'm wondering, how will I layout out my product table after the JSON object is returned? Obviously I can't pass the JSON object back to php and do it that way so would i just recreate my product table with jquery writing a foreach loop for the JSON object and then replacing my container div with that content?

How would you normally and professionally go about doing that?

RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:

well I've written the template in PHP on the initial page load. I am using ajax so I don't have to reload the page.

Here is my PHP

```
<?php foreach($products as $p): ?>
        <div class="indProduct">
            <?php foreach($images as $img): ?>
            <?php if($img['productId'] == $p['id']): ?>
            <div class="prodImg"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/products/<?php echo $img['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $p['productTitle']; ?>" /></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php if($p['salePrice'] != 0.00): ?>
            <div class="prodSaleBanner"></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="prodTitle"><?php echo $p['productTitle']; ?></div>
            <div class="prodPrice">
                <?php if($p['salePrice'] != 0.00): ?>
                $<?php echo number_format($p['salePrice'], 2, '.', ''); ?>
                <?php else: ?>
                $<?php echo number_format($p['price'], 2, '.', ''); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <br />
                <div class="original-price">
                    <?php if($p['salePrice'] != 0.00): ?>
                    $<span style="text-decoration:line-through;"><?php echo number_format($p['price'], 2, '.', ''); ?></span> 
                    <span class="savings">
                        <?php 
                        $savings = $p['price'] - $p['salePrice'];
                        echo 'SAVE: '.number_format($savings, 2, '.', '');
                        ?>
                    </span>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="prodAddButton">
                <a href="<?php echo $p['id']; ?>" id="addToCartButton" class="storeButton">Add To Cart</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

So my plan was to get the JSON object then basically redo all the above code in the ajax success request using jquery and json instead of PHP. Is this a hard way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used code igniter, but what I would do is use a template engine like mustache and define my template with the information I want to display, then pass the json to your template and just render to screen using jQuery. Did I explain my self?

Comment: I'm editing my question as a response to this above (not enough space here).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what you are trying to do, but I find that more difficult than writing your template on Mustache and sending the json to it, then just appending the result or if necessary substitute it with jQuery

Comment: I get what you're saying and if I wasn't half way through the project I would do what you're saying there and make a template just for the view of the product listing. Too far in for that, but you did help me by letting me know what I'm doing is possible at least. haha. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [GoCart](http://gocartdv.com/).  It is based on CodeIgniter and open source [github-url](https://github.com/gocart/GoCart). They also have product catalog. Check their source-code, it might give some idea.

Comment: Yeah I tried GoCart but it doesn't have the drill down functionality that I need and it doesn't have the ajax stuff that i'm trying to do, so I am doing it completely from scratch. However for future projects I think gocart might be a viable option.

Comment: @DanielWhite. Ok, is your code OpenSource, if so I can try to contribute.